# Appstoreconnect API: Testflight's What To Test

Tags: app-store-connect, testflight

I'm trying to update the so called "What To Test" field for an app already uploaded to Testflight, by the Appstoreconnect API introduced during WWDC 2018.

First of all I've got my jwt token using the jwt.rb script shown during the video "Session 303 - Automating Appstoreconnect", presented during WWDC 2018.

That's my BASH shell:

```
TOKEN=$(ruby jwt.rb)
```

Then I'm not even able to get the "What To Test" attribute by the API. I'm only able to see some beta details like those:

```
curl "https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/builds/<id>/buildBetaDetail" --Header "Authorization Bearer:$TOKEN"

{
  "data" : {
    "type" : "buildBetaDetails",
    "id" : "<id>",
    "attributes" : {
      "autoNotifyEnabled" : true,
      "internalBuildState" : "IN_BETA_TESTING",
      "externalBuildState" : "IN_BETA_TESTING"
    },
    "relationships" : {
      "build" : {
        "links" : {
          "self" : "https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/buildBetaDetails/<id>/relationships/build",
          "related" : "https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/buildBetaDetails/<id>/build"
        }
      }
    },
    "links" : {
      "self" : "https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/<id>"
    }
  },
  "links" : {
    "self" : "https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/builds/<id>/buildBetaDetail"
  }
}
```

Which is the HTTP GET I should perform in order to collect What To Test Testflight data for a given `<id>`?

Afterwards, which would be the HTTP PATCH I should perform in order to update it?

Comment: Have you been able to solve it? I'm looking for it and couldn't find anything on the docs :(

Comment: No, it seems an uncovered feature yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent half day reading the api doc (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/modify_a_beta_build_localization) and got the solution. Here are the steps:

1. get the build ID of an app `GET https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/apps/{app_id}/builds`, where {id} is the app id, you can get it from the app's URL of app store connect. You can also get the build ID from the URL `https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/apps/{app_id}/testflight/ios/{build_id}`
2. get the betaBuildLocalizations id with `GET https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/builds/{build_id}/betaBuildLocalizations`
3. Then you can patch the betaBuildLocalizations

```
#!/bin/bash

ENDPOINT="https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1"

# Define your authentication credentials
AUTH_KEY="your AUTH_KEY"
LOCAL_ID="your LOCAL_ID"

PATCH_LOCALE='{
    "whatsNew": "your whatsNew!"
}'

PATCH_DATA='{
    "type": "betaBuildLocalizations",
    "attributes": '$PATCH_LOCALE',
    "id": "'$LOCAL_ID'"
}'

PATCH_PAYLOAD='{
  "data": '$PATCH_DATA'
}'

#PATCH
curl -X PATCH \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $AUTH_KEY" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d "$PATCH_PAYLOAD" \
  "https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/betaBuildLocalizations/$LOCAL_ID"
```

Answer (score 1):

The "what to test" text is localized so it has multiple values. You can find this data in the "whatsNew" attribute of the "betaBuildLocalizations". Use this URL to all build localizations:

`GET/v1/builds/:id/betaBuildLocalizations`

And use this to edit:

`PATCH /v1/betaBuildLocalizations/:id`